# explode Key-Values to key value pair scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 3 lines as input which have key and values are grouped.
Now want to ungroup the values to each key-value pair.

Sample input

```
LKG, LK1, 10, LK2, 20, LK3, 30    
UKG, UK1, 20, UK2, 10, UK5 

SRKG, SRK4, 30, SRK10, 5
```

Expected output

```
LKG,LK1

LKG,LK2

LKG,LK3

UKG,UK1

UKG,UK2

UKG,UK5

SRKG,SRK4

SRKG,SRK10
```

NOTE: integer values like 10,20,30 should not have any key-value pair in the output

I have tried this program but not able to exclude the numbers from given input and key is coming as another key-key pair.

```
    val data = """
    LKG, LK1, 10, LK2, 20, LK3, 30
    UKG, UK1, 20, UK2, 10, UK5
    SRKG, SRK4, 30, SRK10, 5""".trim

    val records = sc.parallelize(data.split('\n'))

    val pairs = records.map(x => (x.split(',')(0), x))

val groupedRDD = pairs.flatMap{case(k, v)=> v.split(",").map(x => (k, x))}
groupedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

Please suggest what can be alternate to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

the following should get your desired output

```
val data = """
LKG, LK1, 10, LK2, 20, LK3, 30
UKG, UK1, 20, UK2, 10, UK5
SRKG, SRK4, 30, SRK10, 5""".trim

data.split("\n").map(_.split(",").filterNot(_.trim.forall(_.isDigit))).flatMap(x => x.tail.map(y => (x(0).trim, y.trim)))
```

calling `.foreach(println)` should give you

```
(LKG,LK1)
(LKG,LK2)
(LKG,LK3)
(UKG,UK1)
(UKG,UK2)
(UKG,UK5)
(SRKG,SRK4)
(SRKG,SRK10)
```